# strftime issues day of the week

Tags: c

```
        char buffer[800];
        struct tm str_time;

        str_time.tm_mday = Cur_Day;
        str_time.tm_mon = Cur_Month - 1;
        str_time.tm_year = entries[i].Year_Start - 1900;
        int len = strftime(buffer, 100, "%A, %d %B %Y", &str_time);
        printf("\n%s\n", buffer);
```

What about the above results in the day of the week always being Sunday, regardless of values of Cur_Day and Cur_Month?

Sample output:

```
Sunday, 23 November 2012
------------------------
stuff

Sunday, 25 November 2012
------------------------
stuff

Sunday, 26 November 2012
------------------------
stuff
```

Comment: There is not enough code to even make a guess here. Such as, what is Cur_Day set to? And Cur_Month, etc.

Comment: The entire segment that's not working is above... Everything else works. Cur_Day is the day of the month that the entry is on (a number between 1 and 31), Cur_Month is the month (a number between 1 and 12).

Comment: @j.w.r The error is obvious from the code shown, if you know what to look for.

Comment: @Zack, & Tyler Yes I see that now. My apologies.

Answer (score 3):

Your `str_time` structure (if, as it seems to be, it's a local variable) has indeterminate values in its fields unless you *explicitly* set them. All `strftime` does is use the values it has, it doesn't first adjust values to conform other fields.

Since you're not setting `tm_wday`, it will stay with whatever it was originally (0 by the looks of it, since it's always Sunday).

If you *do* want to adjust fields based on other fields, you should look into `mktime()`.

From the standard (ISO C99):

> The mktime function converts the broken-down time, expressed as local time, in the
>   structure pointed to by timeptr into a calendar time value with the same encoding as
>   that of the values returned by the time function.
>
> The original values of the tm_wday and tm_yday components of the structure are ignored, and the original values of the other components are not restricted to the ranges indicated above.
>
> On successful completion, the values of the tm_wday and tm_yday components of the structure are set appropriately, and the other components are set to represent the specified calendar time, but with their values forced to the ranges indicated above; the final value of tm_mday is not set until tm_mon and tm_year are determined.

Your best bet is to use `time()` and `localtime()` to populate a `tm` structure, then change the fields you want to change before calling `mktime()`. That way, you're guaranteed that *all* fields will have sensible values.

The following program shows one way to do this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

int main (void) {
    char buffer[100];
    time_t now;
    struct tm *ts;

    // Get today in local time and output it.

    now = time (NULL);
    struct tm *ts = localtime (&now);
    strftime (buffer, 100, "%A, %d %B %Y", ts);
    printf ("Now      = %s\n", buffer);

    // Advance day-of-month and make new date.
    // Probably need to intelligently handle month rollover.

    ts->tm_mday++;
    mktime (ts);
    strftime (buffer, 100, "%A, %d %B %Y", ts);
    printf ("Tomorrow = %s\n", buffer);

    return 0;
}
```

The output of that program is:

```
Now      = Tuesday, 09 October 2012
Tomorrow = Wednesday, 10 October 2012
```

---

For what it's worth, here's a complete program that uses that method to give you the day of the week for a given date (defaults to today).

You can change the year, month and day of month with the optional `-y`, `-m` and `-d` arguments in any order you want, and as many times as you want, though only the last for each type counts.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

static int makeError (char *argVal, char *errStr) {
    printf ("Error with argument '%s': %s\n", argVal, errStr);
    printf ("Usage: dow [-y<year>] [-m<month>] [-d<day>]\n");
    return 1;
}

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int idx, intVal;
    char chVal;
    char buff[100];
    time_t now = time (NULL);
    struct tm *nowStr = localtime (&now);

    for (idx = 1; idx < argc; idx++) {
        chVal = (*argv[idx] != '-') ? '\0' : *(argv[idx] + 1);
        if ((chVal != 'y') && (chVal != 'm') && (chVal != 'd'))
            return makeError (argv[idx], "does not start with '-y/m/d'");

        intVal = atoi (argv[idx] + 2);
        if (intVal < 0)
            return makeError (argv[idx], "suffix is negative");
        sprintf (buff, "%d", intVal);
        if (strcmp (buff, argv[idx] + 2) != 0)
            return makeError (argv[idx], "suffix is not numeric");

        switch (chVal) {
            case 'y': nowStr->tm_year = intVal - 1900; break;
            case 'm': nowStr->tm_mon = intVal - 1; break;
            case 'd': nowStr->tm_mday = intVal; break;
        }
    }

    mktime (nowStr);
    strftime (buff, sizeof (buff), "%A, %d %B %Y", nowStr);
    printf ("%s\n", buff);

    return 0;
}
```

A sample transcript:

```
pax> ./dow
Tuesday, 09 October 2012

pax> ./dow -y2011
Sunday, 09 October 2011

pax> ./dow -y2000 -m1 -d1
Saturday, 01 January 2000
```

Comment: +1 because I had no idea `mktime`/`timegm` had the side effect of normalizing the `tm` structure.

Answer (score 1):

The most probable explanation is that your `strftime` requires `tm_wday` to have a meaningful value if you're going to ask it to print the day of the week.

This is the simplest available way to avoid having to compute it yourself:

```
struct tm tm;

memset(&tm, 0, sizeof(struct tm));
tm.tm_mday = Cur_Day;
tm.tm_mon = Cur_Month - 1;
tm.tm_year = entries[i].Year_Start - 1900;
tm.tm_hour = 12;

(void) timegm(&tm); /* fills in the rest of `tm` as a side effect */

/* now call strftime */
```

If you don't have `timegm` you MAY be able to get away with using `mktime` instead (the problems with doing this calculation in 'local' time are largely irrelevant if you only want to print the *date*).  DO NOT use the "portable version of `timegm`" described in the Linux manpage for `timegm`, it has portability gotchas waiting to bite on almost every line!

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `str_time.tm_wday` so that `strftime()` can convert it.

See [localtime(3)](http://linux.die.net/man/3/localtime) and [strftime(3)](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strftime) for examples.